# Default "Assigned To" on Task Creation

Tags: error, tasks, queue, global-actions

When creating a new task, I would like the "Assigned To" field to default to a specific queue. On the Global Action, I am trying to add it as a Predefined Field Value, but the formula editor is not loving this idea.

I have tried to use the name of the queue, the Salesforce Id of the queue, used it by itself, also as part of a formula (OwnerId = 'Finance').

When OwnerId (the API Name of the AssignedTo field) is included I get *OwnerId may not be used in this type of formula* and when I remove it, I get *Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Lookup(Calendar,Group,User)).* - it also says this when I use the Salesforce Id of a User.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Is there a reason you can't use Assignment Rules for this?

Comment: You can able to refer the $User.ID instead of hardcoding the value in your predefined values of lookup field.  refer the https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8A7oSAF